# how to avoid Invalid character found in the request target error in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

how to avoid Invalid character found in the request target error in spring boot, prior to being processed by the underlying servlet container

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21 ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:494) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:269) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54] 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

Comment: Give more info about this problem

Comment: Maybe stop sending it invalid characters? Your request has a tab ("\t") in it.

Comment: @WhiteBite these are not requests sent by us, but we do traces in log files because someone else is sending these payloads to the server endpoint

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek we are not sending invalid characters, we don't know who does it as the arguments indicate they are trying to invoke some kind of a PHP function. the question is how can I avoid this by using a filter or any other mechanism